# How can I use SheepIt data injection more then one time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-injection

I have a big problem using the jQuery plugin SheepIt.

First I load on document ready the following code:

```
var handleDayExtension = function() {

    if (!jQuery().sheepIt && !index) {
      return;
    }

    sheepItForm = $('#dayExtension').sheepIt({
        separator: '',
        allowRemoveLast: true,
        allowRemoveCurrent: true,
        allowRemoveAll: true,
        allowAdd: true,
        allowAddN: false,
        maxFormsCount: 0,
        minFormsCount: 0,
        iniFormsCount: 0,
        data: day_edit_data,
        beforeAdd: function(source) {
            App.blockUI({target: $('#days'), iconOnly: true});
        },
        afterAdd: function(source, newForm) {
            handleDatePickers(1);
            handleTimePickers();
            App.unblockUI($('#days'));
        }
    });
}
```

Then, when I click a button, the following code loads:

```
var handelGenerateDays = function() {

    var startDate = moment($('#start').val(), 'DD.MM.YYYY')._d,
        endDate = moment($('#end').val(), 'DD.MM.YYYY')._d,
        startTime = $('#startTime').val(),
        endTime = $('#endTime').val(),
        repetition = $('#repetition').val(),
        repetition_days = $('#repetition_days').val().sort(Coursedates.numsort),
        days = "",
        day_data = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < repetition; ++i) {

        for (var d = 0; d < repetition_days.length; ++d) {

            var days = new Object;

            days['dayExtension_#index#_date'] = moment( Coursedates.nextDay( startDate, repetition_days[d] ) ).format("DD.MM.YYYY");
            days['dayExtension_#index#_start'] = startTime;
            days['dayExtension_#index#_end'] = endTime;

            day_data.push(days);

            startDate = new Date( Coursedates.nextDay( startDate, repetition_days[d] ) );
        }
    }
    sheepItForm.inject(day_data);
}
```

It works fine. But when I click again on the button, the rows are created but without values.

Can I not use data injection more than once?